# If no posts exist for current day and month, show the next available day of posts

Tags: posts, wp-query, date-query

I'm writing an on this day function which should show the X number of posts for the current day and month.

How can I add a fallback to the query if there are no posts, to show the next available day of posts?

These are the arguments I'm passing to the current day query.

```
    $onThisDay_args = array(
      'post_type' => array('on-this-day'),
      'posts_per_page' => $postlimit,
      'date_query' => array(
        array(
          'month' => date( 'n', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ),
          'day' => date( 'j', current_time( 'timestamp' ) )
        ),
      )
    );
```

The only way I can think of executing this requirement is if the results from the first query equal null or 0, then run the second query.

If that is the case, how do I modify the date_query arguments to fallback to the previous day of available posts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How to solve this depends very much how you store it.

In general I would be aware of letting WordPress handle historical dates, of broad range, as post dates. There are various limitations that you can check on this site or eg. trac.

**Date query for yesterday**

If you create a *datetime* object with:

```
 $dto = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-n-j', current_time( 'Y-n-j' ) );
```

where the *timezone* is included in the `current_time()`, then you can try to set it to the d*ay before* with:

```
 $dto->modify( 'yesterday' );
```

The *month* and *day* for *yesterday* should be accessible with:

```
'date_query' => [
    [
        'month' => $dto->format('n'),
        'day'   => $dto->format('j'),
     ],
],
```

For 2 days before we can try

```
$dto->modify( '-2 days' );
```

and so on

**Date query for the current date or the previous available date**

If you use the same year for all events, then you can use:

```
'date_query' => [
    [
        'before'      => current_time( 'Y-n-j' ),
        'inclusive'   => true,
     ],
],
```

**Alternatives**

For a very sparse month-day list, one could try to group posts by month and day to find the previous available post date. But this would need a custom query.

One could also use a custom database table to store the dates, for more flexibility, but that also needs a custom building.

Many event plugins store the dates in the post meta, and use `meta_query` in `WP_Query` to filter through it. But this might not scale well for large number of posts.

We could even use a custom taxonomy to store the month-day, but then the month-day ordering might get tricky.